# How to configure CMake in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, vcpkg

I have a shell script to build a project on Ubuntu 18.04 that works. I would also like to build the project from Eclipse so that I have better code navigation and debugging. When I build the project I get the error

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!  
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.  
Modules directory not found in  
/usr/share/cmake-3.16  
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
```

I have CMake installed at */opt/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/* and also deep under *vcpkg*. My shell script and my preference is to use the version (3.14) under *vcpkg*. CMAKE_ROOT seems to be generated by the script

```
../../../vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.14.0-linux/cmake-3.14.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -G Ninja -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../../vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=./../../vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/doctest -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/boost_1_72_0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S ../
```

In Eclipse (2019-12, 4.14.0), I tried defining CMAKE_ROOT in Properties | C/C++ Build | Cmake4eclipse | Symbols tab and in Properties | C/C++ Build | Environment.

The log shows a mix of references to files under */opt/cmake/share/cmake-3.16* and files deep under *vcpkg* (3.14).

How do I control which version of cmake to run from Eclipse?

The project is also built and tested in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but have you tried changing the value set under: Properties | C/C++ Build | Cmake4eclipse | Host OS overrides | Linux | Cmake Executable?

Comment: Yes, after posting the question. It produced: Error: Program "~/develop/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.14.0-linux/cmake-3.14.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake" not found in PATH. I did not expect it to be in the path.

Comment: There was a conflict in the Tool Chain Editor. I reduced the Used Tools to CMake driven Languages Proxy. Now it hangs doing _/usr/bin/make -j 2147483647 clean_.